# This transaction will likely fail - Gnosis Safe and StrongBlock claiming

Tags: gas, gnosis-safe, gnosis, failed-transaction

Situation:

Using Gnosis Safe with app.StrongBlock.com

When we try to claim rewards from all nodes we get the following error in Gnosis safe:

[image: Gnosis Safe Transaction will likely fail]

We have tried adjusting the gas limit/fee/priority fee etc but still get the same "this transaction will likely fail" message.

[image: Updated gas limits but still likely fail message]

Is this something to do with Gnosis or a problem with StrongBlock proxy contracts?

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Can you share the transaction information (to and data)

Answer (score 0):

So without knowing the concrete data I have to make some guesses:

I guess the contract you interact with is https://etherscan.io/address/0xfbddadd80fe7bda00b901fbaf73803f2238ae655#code

TL;DR: you need to use `claim` instead of `claimAll` (not sure if this is supported by their interface.)

Details:
Assuming that you are calling `claimAll` function then the issue is related to how the `Service17` contract (the implementation contract the proxy points to) works.

The `claimAll` function performs a call to the `claim` function where it forwards a part of the value:

```js
function claimAll(uint256 blockNumber, bool toStrongPool) public payable {
    uint256 value = msg.value;
    for (uint16 i = 1; i <= entityNodeCount[msg.sender]; i++) {
      uint256 reward = getRewardByBlock(msg.sender, i, blockNumber);
      uint256 fee = reward.mul(claimingFeeNumerator).div(claimingFeeDenominator);
      require(value >= fee, "invalid fee");
      if (reward > 0) {
        // The contract calls itself to handle the claim
        require(this.claim{value : fee}(i, blockNumber, toStrongPool), "claim failed");
      }
      value = value.sub(fee);
    }
  }
```

Because of this the `msg.sender` is changed from the calling address to the contract itself. To handle this `claim` method has a special check:

```js
address sender = msg.sender == address(this) || msg.sender == address(strongNFTBonus) ? tx.origin : msg.sender;
```

If this method is called by the contract itself than the `sender` is set to `tx.origin`. This is problematic when the original caller is a smart contract, as this is not the same as `tx.origin`. Therefore it tries then to claim funds for a different account.

By directly calling `claim` instead of `claimAll` this check will not be triggered and claiming will still work.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your reply. So are we unable to use Gnosis when claiming all nodes (claimAll function)? 

We have successfully used Gnosis to claim on one individual node, so the normal "claim" function works. 

Is the Gnosis smart contract address different from the Gnosis safe wallet address? That's what is causing the problem?

Comment: The problem is that `claimAll` relies on `tx.origin`, which is the account that submitted the transaction to the Ethereum chain (e.g. the code that is the `from` on Etherscan). In the current state of Ethereum this is never a contract (so also not the Safe).